# Server-side won't recognize elements from $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I'm asking here probably with simple problem. I add elements on page using Javascript/Jquery. Elements which I added with Jquery works fine and I can get them to variables in php. But the problem is with Javascript one.

When I'm checking on browser, I can see that my created elements `<h6>` in my case is named as I want `meal_category[1]; meal_category[2]` etc... name and id is the same. But when I'm trrying to `print_r` element for some reason I get `Notice: Undefined index: meal_category[1] in ...` I'm sure that it is indeed defined, but php just won't recognize it somehow. Here is one of generated elements pasted from browser `inspect element` for example:

```
<h6 class="d-xl-flex justify-content-xl-center align-items-xl-center mb-2" id="meal_category[1]" name="meal_category[1]" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background: rgb(255, 35, 81); border-radius: 15px; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;">Burgeriai
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="removeCategory[1]" onclick="removeCategory(this)" type="button" style="background: transparent;border-style: none;padding: 0px;margin-left: 3px;">X</button>
</h6>
```

I don't know if I explained everything clear, let me know if something's missing. Also here's my php code:

```
$mealCategories = $_POST['meal_category'];

$ingredientNames = $_POST['ingredient_name']; 
$ingredientPrices = $_POST['ingredient_price']; 
$mealsizeSelect = $_POST['mealsize_select']; 
$mealsizeCorrect = $_POST['mealsize_correct'];

print_r($mealCategories[1]);
```

all the other elements worked, except for `meal_category` one. Is it because I created other elements using Jquery and this using js? Below is how I create this `<h6>`.

```
var cat = document.createElement('H6');
cat.className = 'd-xl-flex justify-content-xl-center align-items-xl-center mb-2';
cat.style = 'margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px;background: #ff2351;color: rgb(255,255,255)!important;border-radius: 15px;font-size: 14px;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 6px;';
cat.id = 'meal_category['+selectCategory.counter+']';
cat.setAttribute('name', 'meal_category['+selectCategory.counter+']');

cat.innerHTML = selectedText + '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="removeCategory['+selectCategory.counter+']" onClick="removeCategory(this)" type="button" style="background: transparent;border-style: none;padding: 0px;margin-left: 3px;">X</button>';
document.getElementById('selectedCategories').appendChild(cat);
```

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($mealCategories)` (without the explicitly specified index)?

Comment: How is this data even transferred to PHP? Is there an AJAX call somewhere?

Comment: Everything's is in the `<form action="uploadmeal.php" method="POST"></form>` so it's transferred with "POST" method

Comment: Output is the same, it seems to fail to find `$_POST['meal_category']`, but it's there for sure

Comment: `h6` is not a form element so it seems normal it's not detected. Are other elements also header tags?

Comment: Others are `<input>` elements, I get it now, basically, `<form>` cannot see elements like `<div>`, `<h6>`... right?

Comment: Agree with @El_Vanja. You should use input tags inside a form to access it using POST on php

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a regular form submission is executed, only [form elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp) will be submitted. Current list of form elements from the documentation:

- `<input>`
- `<label>`
- `<select>`
- `<textarea>`
- `<button>`
- `<fieldset>`
- `<legend>`
- `<datalist>`
- `<output>`
- `<option>`
- `<optgroup>`

Since your elements are `<h6>` tags, they won't be detected, despite the fact you attached a `name` attribute to them.